# Python Error - NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.Text'>'

Tags: python, notimplementedexception

I'm getting the error below from some Python code. Can anyone help me figure out what is going on? I tried to embed the full code, but I kept getting an error saying my code was not properly formatted. I'll try to post a reply with the full code!

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.Text'>'

```
**Code:**

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [122], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('R', '-i cutoff -i mtry -i ntree -i data -o max_f1 -o max_cut -o max_mtry -o max_ntree -o max_precision -o max_recall', 'library(randomForest)\n\nfrom types import NoneType\nNoneType = type(None)\n\n#from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell\n#InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"\n\n#9-24-2022 SL\n#from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter as lc\n\n#with lc(ro.default_converter + pr.converter):\n#  fileName_c = ro.conversion.py2rpy(fileName)\n#  url_c = ro.conversion.py2rpy(url)\n#ro.globalenv[\'fileName\'] = fileName_c\n#ro.globalenv[\'url\'] = url_c\n\n#from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri\n\n\n#pandas2ri.activate()\n#end 9-24-2022 SL\n\ndata$target = factor(data$target)\ncutoff_list = unlist(strsplit("0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9",","))  #cutoff 9-24-2022 SL\nmtry_list = unlist(strsplit("2,3,4,5",","))  #mtry 9-24-2022 SL\nntree_list = unlist(strsplit("100,500,1000",","))  #ntree 9-24-2022 SL\nset.seed(830)\nmax_f1 = 0\nmax_cut = 0\nmax_mtry = 0\nmax_ntree = 0\nmax_precision = 0\nmax_recall = 0\n# a nested for loop for ntree, mtry, cutoff?\nfor (cut in cutoff_list )\n{\n    for (Mtry in mtry_list)\n    {\n        for (Ntree in ntree_list)\n        {\n            cut = as.numeric(cut) #9-24-2022 SL cut - should be "cutoff"?\n            Mtry = as.numeric(mtry) #9-24-2022 SL mtry\n            Ntree = as.numeric(NTree) #9-24-2022 SL Ntree\n            fit_data <- randomForest(data$target ~ ., data=data, importance=TRUE, proximity=TRUE, cutoff=c(cut, 1-cut), ntree=Ntree, mtry=Mtry)\n            true_positives = fit_data$confusion[\'1\',\'1\']\n            true_negatives = fit_data$confusion[\'0\',\'0\']\n            false_positives = fit_data$confusion[\'0\',\'1\']\n            false_negatives = fit_data$confusion[\'1\',\'0\']\n            accuracy = (true_positives + true_negatives)/nrow(data)\n            precision = true_positives/(true_positives+false_positives)\n            recall = true_positives/(true_positives + false_negatives)\n            f1_score = 2*((recall*precision)/(precision+recall))\n            if (! is.nan(f1_score) && f1_score > max_f1)\n            {\n                max_f1 = f1_score\n                max_cut = cut\n                max_mtry = Mtry\n                max_ntree = Ntree\n                max_precision = precision\n                max_recall = recall\n            }\n        }\n    }\n}\n\n')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2347, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2345 with self.builtin_trap:
   2346     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2347     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2348 return result

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py:755, in RMagics.R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    753                 raise NameError("name '%s' is not defined" % input)
    754         with localconverter(converter) as cv:
--> 755             ro.r.assign(input, val)
    757 if args.display:
    758     try:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py:203, in SignatureTranslatedFunction.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    201         v = kwargs.pop(k)
    202         kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 203 return (super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self)
    204         .__call__(*args, **kwargs))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py:118, in Function.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    116 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    117     cv = conversion.get_conversion()
--> 118     new_args = [cv.py2rpy(a) for a in args]
    119     new_kwargs = {}
    120     for k, v in kwargs.items():
    121         # TODO: shouldn't this be handled by the conversion itself ?

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py:118, in <listcomp>(.0)
    116 def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    117     cv = conversion.get_conversion()
--> 118     new_args = [cv.py2rpy(a) for a in args]
    119     new_kwargs = {}
    120     for k, v in kwargs.items():
    121         # TODO: shouldn't this be handled by the conversion itself ?

File ~\anaconda3\lib\functools.py:888, in singledispatch.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kw)
    884 if not args:
    885     raise TypeError(f'{funcname} requires at least '
    886                     '1 positional argument')
--> 888 return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\numpy2ri.py:134, in nonnumpy2rpy(obj)
    129     return ro.default_converter.py2rpy(obj)
    130 elif original_converter is None:
    131     # This means that the conversion module was not "activated".
    132     # For now, go with the default_converter.
    133     # TODO: the conversion system needs an overhaul badly.
--> 134     return ro.default_converter.py2rpy(obj)
    135 else:
    136     # The conversion module was "activated"
    137     return original_converter.py2rpy(obj)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\functools.py:888, in singledispatch.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kw)
    884 if not args:
    885     raise TypeError(f'{funcname} requires at least '
    886                     '1 positional argument')
--> 888 return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\conversion.py:240, in _py2rpy(obj)
    238 if isinstance(obj, _rinterface_capi.SupportsSEXP):
    239     return obj
--> 240 raise NotImplementedError(
    241     "Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '%s'" %
    242     str(type(obj))
    243 )

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.Text'>'
```

Comment: Well the conversion from python to R is not defined for objects of type **ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.Text**

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I there were some input parameters that I needed to hit  for prior steps to store them properly. Once I did that, the above error got resolved.

Fair point, TY Robin! The resolution to my error was that prior steps had a text box widget input/prompt. I needed to press  after entering into those textbox widgets. Once I did so, subsequent model building steps recognized those inputs. Pressing  was key

Comment: When posting on StackOverflow, try to ask questions and answer in a way that is useful to others as well! :) Could you edit your post and answer so that other visitors who make the same mistake know what to do to solve it?

Comment: Fair point, TY Robin! The resolution to my error was that prior steps had a text box widget input/prompt. I needed to press <enter> after entering into those textbox widgets. Once I did so, subsequent model building steps recognized those inputs. Pressing <enter> was key.

Comment: Nice! Can you edit your answer and put it there? Comments may dissapear at any time :)